# Why am i able to use this keyword with static variables in java

Tags: java, static, this

I am a beginner in java and i am trying to understand the concept of **static** from a book I bought to learn java. But, because of my experiments in the program, I am very confused. The book says that static could not refer to this keyword, which is fine until I started using normal functions instead of static. In this, I was able to access the static variable with the this keyword!! (see the displayMobileSpecs function in the code below)

```
import java.util.Random;

class Static {
     public static void main(String[] com){

         System.out.println("By default the mobile is having " 
                             + Mobile.RAM + "gigabytes of RAM and"
                             + Mobile.CameraMP + " mega pixels of camera");

         Mobile S4mini = new Mobile("S4 Mini" , 4 , 16);
         S4mini.displayMobileSpecs(true);

         Mobile mob2 = new Mobile("fdf" , 23 , 45);
         mob2.displayMobileSpecs(true);
         S4mini.displayMobileSpecs(false);
     }
}

class Mobile{

    static int RAM;
    static int CameraMP;
    Random rand = new Random();

    double InternalMemorySpace;
    double ExternalMemorySpace;

    String modelNo;

    Mobile(String modelName,double internalMem , double externalMem)
    {
        this.modelNo = modelName;
        this.InternalMemorySpace = internalMem;
        this.ExternalMemorySpace = externalMem;
    }

    static {
        RAM = 4;
        CameraMP = 12;

        System.out.println("The Static part of the class is executed");
    }

    void displayMobileSpecs(boolean change){

        if(change)
        this.RAM = (int) rand.nextInt(8) + 2;

        System.out.println(this.RAM + " , " + Mobile.RAM);
    }
}
```

So is it that static variables could be accessed using this but not in the static functions or what?? I am really confused and this is a very silly question as I see it, but please answer me.

(Note: by the way, please don't mind the ridiculous example of mobile used in the program. thanks :) )

Answer (score 3):

> static variables could be accessed using this but not in the static
>   functions

In static block or a static method, there is no instance to refer to, and therefore the "this" keyword is not permitted.

> Why am i able to use this keyword with static variables in java

But you can refer "this" in a non static method also you can use refer static variable with "this" keyword in the non static method.Here "this" points to current object.

Comment: You can refer to a static member through an instance reference like `this`, but you shouldn't.

Comment: I agree .....but my answer was  limited to OPs questions, you are taking it dos and donts. Thanks for adding that.